# First Posts Review Queue doesn't show Code Snippet

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, stack-snippets

In the First Posts Review Queue, I came across this answer:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

When you right click the question and open it in a new tab, this is what it looks like outside of the Review Queue:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

The version inside the Review Queue does not show that there is a code snippet present.  That could be a problem when determining whether or not the post needs to be flagged or not.

Comment: duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239529/stack-snippets-are-not-shown-properly-in-the-review-queue

Comment: Not quite - that's suggested edit queue (so, the diff renderer) this is the review renderer. Still a bug.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It really helps if I actually include the Stack Snippets JavaScript file reference in the review queue. I have done so now and this should be working properly. Without the JavaScript, it was rendering an invisible div for snippets that were hidden by default. Should be good to go now.